# Wordpress form plugin only get one field in hook

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I downloaded the plugin ninja forms, and I created a form. as PHP code, I got my own plugin, which renders PHP code before each field, using this hook:

http://ninjaforms.com/documentation/developer-api/actions/ninja_forms_display_before_field/

```
function test() {
    $output = "hello";
    echo $output;
    return $output;
}
```

`add_action('ninja_forms_display_before_field','test');`

Now it looks like:

> hello
>  field
>  hello
>  field
>  hello
>  field

my Questions:
How can I use this hook, on only one field? I saw the example on the link i have written before - but I don't really understand how this helps me(new to wordpress). 
I probably have to pass some kind of parameter to the hook, but I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create two additional parameters, which I can check with the if-statement:

```
function checkFieldId($field_id, $data) {
    //var_dump($field_id);
    if($field_id == 11 ){
        placeholder();
    }
}
```

`add_action('ninja_forms_display_before_field','checkFieldId', 10, 2);`